# Don't execute if there is an error and print error message

Tags: lua

This is pretty self explanatory but...

```
if input~=nil then
    docom=loadstring(input)
    print(docom())
else
    print("Command execution failed")
end
```

I know my error on the if statement but my point is how do i not run it if it is not a valid Lua command and instead print an error. and if it is valid Lua how do I make sure errors just get stopped and it runs a printed error message without crashing. I'm on linux btw if it requires `os.execute()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadstring` (or `load`, since Lua 5.2) returns `nil` plus the error message if the chunk has syntactic errors. So you could just check the result of `load` like this:

```
local chunk = 'foo'
local f, err = loadstring(chunk)
if not f then
    print(err)
else
    f()
end
```